# Where do "stock" comments come from?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

I often see copy/paste comments to common post problems. Things such as

> While a link to a potential solution is always welcome, an answer on
>   Stack Overflow should always contain the main parts/points of the
>   solution in the answer body itself.

or

> Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read [the help
>   pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and provide a [Minimal,
>   Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Is there a page with recommended comment templates somewhere, or do people just maintain these personally?

**Edit:**

Should Stack Overflow have a list like this?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Can you explain?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/search?q=stock+comments

Comment: Some of the apps provides a set of predefined/canned messages.

Comment: I think it would be useful to have a list of these canned messages. It would most likely be more polite and complete than what is quick to write. Things like, "Can you show us what you have tried?" etc.

Comment: Perhaps more polite and complete, but also perhaps colder and less relevant to the specific question. (I'm not saying it is a bad idea, but merely pointing out there is a trade-off in using boilerplate comments.)

Comment: @mhatch yes... but the apps are not built by Stack but by the users... so that list needs to come from the coders of the Apps

Comment: @Patrice Is there a way to dump them from the app itself?

Comment: @mhatch terrific question! Never really played with the apps, so can't help ya there. Considering there are likely multiple apps with stock comments, and that there are some OTHER stock comments out there (for instance when you vote to close/flag).... a complete list might not be possible without some legwork on your part

Comment: The [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) app allows you to enter your own list of comments using Markdown, and to import and export the list. If you visit that page, it lists all its features.

Comment: You can extract the canned comments from the source of the app, it's fairly trivial. Just look for `var defaultcomments`. This tool allows users to maintain their own canned comments, and various users have posted their lists in various locations. As said by others, the major problem that people run into when using canned comments is that they come out very cold to the recipient, and they may not always be tailored to the specific post.

Comment: I don't think SO itself should try to maintain a list of these: there's multiple apps and some users do just maintain these themselves. I personally often quote from either http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic or from the flag dialog options.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MadaraUchiha/3881905

Comment: SOCVR host canned comments as well: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments